# How to click on the Next button with doPostBack() call to browse to the next page while fetching data with Selenium and Python?

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, webdriverwait, dopostback

I have written this code but its not going on the next page its fetching data from the same page repeatedly.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

url="http://www.4docsearch.com/Delhi/Doctors"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(url)

next_page = True
while next_page == True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    div = soup.find('div',{"id":"ContentPlaceHolder1_divResult"})

    for heads in div.find_all('h2'):       
        links = heads.find('a')
        print(links['href'])

    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//* [@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkNext"]""").click()
    except:
        print ('No more pages')
        next_page=False

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To browse to the **Next** page as the desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element with `__doPostBack()` you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the `staleness_of()` the element first.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` the element next.
- You can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Code Block:

    ```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    chrome_options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("http://www.4docsearch.com/Delhi/Doctors")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkNext' and not(@class='aspNetDisabled')]"))).click()
    while True:
        try:
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.staleness_of((driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkNext' and not(@class='aspNetDisabled')]"))))
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_lnkNext' and not(@class='aspNetDisabled')]"))).click()
            print ("Next")
        except:
            print ("No more pages")
            break
    print ("Exiting")
    driver.quit()
    ```
  - Console Output

    ```
    Next
    Next
    Next
    .
    .
    .
    No more pages
    Exiting
    ```

Comment: You have to capture the element that you want to go stale BEFORE the click that updates the page or you will have a race condition.